# Открытие окна диалога PyQT5 Python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Как открыть диалоговое окно в классе? Через доп функцию в принципе понятно.
Есть код (пример урезан):

```
class Software(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Software, self).__init__()
        self.MW = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.MW.setupUi(self)
        self.operation()            # Функция обработки нажатий
 
    def operation(self):
        self.MW.butAddCategory.clicked.connect(lambda: CataStor(1))    # Клик ДОБАВИТЬ (парам. 1)

class CataStor(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, selector):
        super(CataStor, self).__init__()
        self.selector = selector
        self.window()
       
    def window(self):
        print(self.selector)  <--- Сюда все приходит и печатает. А вот само окно не отображается
 
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.setWindowTitle("TEST")
        self.pushButton.setText('Button')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Software()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Главное окно открывается и работает. А вот как заставить окно CataStor появиться никак не пойму. Пробовал и show, и exec_. Но видимо не там располагаю.

Comment: После `self.window()` добавьте `self.exec_()`

Comment: Огромное спасибо. А то уже все вроде перепробовал и глаз "замылился"!